# How can I decode a list of lists?

Tags: c++, yaml-cpp

I have the following YAML file I need to decode in Yaml-CPP

```
WorldMatrix:
- [0.9951964247911349, 0.018388246064889716, -0.09615585520185603, -0.5403611888912607]
- [0.0668777651703494, 0.5895969306048771, 0.8049241106757379, 0.49102218903854067]
- [0.0714943396973693, -0.8074882858766219, 0.5855349926035782, 3.057906332726323]
- [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0]
```

I have gotten as far as such, but I can't figure out how to continue:

```
YAML::Node config = YAML::LoadFile(path);
for(YAML::const_iterator it=config.begin(); it != config.end(); ++it){


}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to store it using `std::vector`, there's a shortcut:

```
YAML::Node config = YAML::LoadFile(path);
std::vector<std::vector<double>> worldMatrix =
    config["WorldMatrix"].as<std::vector<std::vector<double>>>();
```

If you simply want to iterate over it and do whatever you like:

```
for (YAML::Node row : config["WorldMatrix"]) {
  for (YAML::Node col : row) {
    double value = col.as<double>();
    // do something with value
  }
}
```

Comment: I dont think this is correct.t your code gives me a seg fault

Comment: i think there may be a bug in yaml-cpp. this must definitely work.

Comment: do you think you can try out my structure and your code. I've spent the last 4 hours trying to get this to work.

Comment: I just verified that both work on OS X, 10.10.5 with clang 7, at the tip of the repo. Could you post the stack trace? Also, could you verify the version of yaml-cpp that you are linking and including?

Comment: can i know the compile flags you used in g++

Comment: also..i am using cmake..where i specify
target_link_libraries(file_viewer yaml-cpp)